# Async fetch and trouble a copy array in class

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await

I have a problem... thant's a code:

```
class Currency {
    cosnstructor() {
        this.currencyInfo = [];
    }

    getCurrency(getInfo) {
        this.currencyInfo = getInfo;
    }    
}

const actuallyCurrency = new Currency;

(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A`);
        const data = await response.json();
        const currency = data[0].rates; 
        currency.map(element => curArr.push(element));
})();

const curArr = [];

actuallyCurrency.getCurrency(curArr);
```

this code working good, but I need in this.currencyInfo a new array, not reference to array curArr.

Comment: you need `const curArr = []; actuallyCurrency.getCurrency(curArr);` **inside** the async IIFE - since at the moment, the code AFTER the IIFE is executed BEFORE the fetch completes

Comment: or just `actuallyCurrency.getCurrency([...currency]);` instead of the `currency.map` code - no need for `curArr` at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I this this is what you want:

```js
    class Currency {
        constructor() {
            this.currencyInfo = [];
        }
    
        getCurrency(getInfo) {
            this.currencyInfo = [...getInfo]; // <-- change this line
        }    
    }
    
    const actuallyCurrency = new Currency;
    
    (async () => {
        const response = { json: () => { return [{rates:{a:1, b:2, c:3}}];}};
//        const response = await fetch(`http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A`);
          const data = await response.json();
          const currency = data[0].rates; 
          for(key in currency) curArr.push(currency[key]);
            
         actuallyCurrency.getCurrency(curArr);
         console.log(actuallyCurrency.currencyInfo);

    })();
    
const curArr = [];
```

Some thing for you to understand:

1-`...` is an operator that does a shallow copy of it's argument. So using as above you'll get a new array in currencyInfo.

2-Why `actuallyCurrency.getCurrency(curArr);           console.log(actuallyCurrency.currencyInfo);` have to be inside the function ?

because os the async nature of the operation. Asyncs are postponed to when the execution has finished so the execution arrives in actuallyCurrency.getCurrency(curArr) BEFORE curArr is populated. This makes the internal currencyInfo array being null and not being populated again after execution.

3-Why this `currency.map(element => curArr.push(element));` doesn't work ?

Because currency is an object, not an iterable array. If you want to iterate the elements of an object you have to options: get it's keys as an array, iterate this array and then get the value using it's key OR using for...in as I did.

Hope this is enough. Fell free to ask any question you'd like

Comment: when I paste ur solution in development mode in chrome I still have a empty array currencyInfo ... and that's is my trouble.. any solutions i see empty array. Only take references I see fully

Comment: K. Made a working version. Check it now.

Comment: Thank you for a explaining my problem. Now, I can inside async function send directly to object, like as: ` for(key in currency) actuallyCurrency.currencyInfo.push(currency[key]); `

Comment: Yes you can. It's a public member. There are ways to hide an object property. But with that structure you used, all members are public

Answer (score 0):

There are a few improvements to be made. Probably the most important is arranging to check the `currencyInfo`  instance variable after the fetch completes.  This and other suggestions indicated by comments...

```
class Currency {
  cosnstructor() {
    this.currencyInfo = [];
  }

  // methods that assign (and don't return anything) ought to be called "set" something
  setCurrency(array) {
    this.currencyInfo = array;  
  }

  // it probably makes sense to have this class do it's own async initialization
  async fetchCurrency() {
    const url = `http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A`;
    // try/catch, so we can respond to failures
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      // no need to map and not sure why the array needs to be copied. I suspect
      // it doesn't but [...array] copies array
      this.setCurrency([...data[0].rates]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error fetching', error);
    }
  }   
}

// instantiation requires ()
const actuallyCurrency = new Currency();

// no async/await at the top level
actuallyCurrency.fetchCurrency().then(() => {
  console.log(actuallyCurrency.currencyInfo);
})
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I do not fully understand this code, becouse I  am taking first steps in JS, but this working!